# Vite dev version works but when the built version does not

Tags: javascript, typescript, vite

- wikibase-sdk version: ^9.1.0
- Environment: Firefox / Chromium latest

Error:

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: can't access lexical declaration 'simplifyEntities' before initialization
    <anonymous> http://localhost:4173/assets/propertyEditor-b00fceb9.js:1075
```

[image]

Bug does not occurr in development (running `vite`), only when building for production. Project repo: https://github.com/PDA-UR/graphit-frontend/tree/dev

Scripts:

```
"dev": "vite",
"build:dev": "tsc && vite build",
```

Building for production is done via `tsc && vite build`. Vite config:

```
// vite.config.js
export default {
    // config options
    build: {
        outDir: "dist",
        emptyOutDir: true,
        minify: false,
        sourcemap: true,
        mode: "development",
        rollupOptions: {
            input: {
                home: "./index.html",
                visTest: "./src/pages/visTest/index.html",
                propertyEditor: "src/pages/propertyEditor/index.html",
            },
        },
    },
};
```

I guess the relevant code is this part, but the error doesn't give me a line number on my end. The error occurs in the sdk.

```
import { WBK } from "wikibase-sdk";
import type { SparqlResults } from "wikibase-sdk";

// Dont use this class directly, use the SparqlClient class instead

export default class QueryDispatcher {
    private readonly instance = "https://graphit.ur.de";
    private readonly endpoint =
        "https://query.graphit.ur.de/proxy/wdqs/bigdata/namespace/wdq/sparql";

    private readonly wbk = WBK({
        sparqlEndpoint: this.endpoint,
        instance: this.instance,
    });

    async query(sparql: string): Promise<SparqlResults> {
        const url = this.wbk.sparqlQuery(sparql);
        const headers = {};

        const response = await fetch(url, { headers });
        const data = await response.json();
        return data;
    }
}
```

Query I'm trying to execute:

```
const query = `PREFIX wdt: <https://graphit.ur.de/prop/direct/>
SELECT 
  ?source ?sourceLabel 
  ?sourceNodeClass ?sourceNodeClassLabel ?sourceNodeImage 
  ?dependency ?dependencyLabel
  ?dependencyNodeClass ?dependencyNodeClassLabel ?dependencyNodeImage 
WHERE {
  # Retrieve the source node and its dependent node
  ?source wdt:P1 ?dependency.
  
  # Retrieve the class of the source node
  ?source wdt:P2 ?sourceNodeClass.
  
  # Retrieve the image of the source node (if available)
  OPTIONAL { ?source wdt:P9 ?sourceNodeImage. }
  
  # Retrieve the class of the dependent node (if available)
  OPTIONAL { ?dependency wdt:P2 ?dependencyNodeClass. }
  
  # Retrieve the image of the dependent node (if available)
  OPTIONAL { ?dependency wdt:P9 ?dependencyNodeImage. }
  
  # Retrieve labels for all entities in the preferred language (fallback to English)
  SERVICE wikibase:label { bd:serviceParam wikibase:language "[AUTO_LANGUAGE],en". }
}
`;
```

I also built the project using Webpack and it works fine. It only does not work using the vite build command.

Why does the project wokr fine when running it via `vite` but whenever I build it and start a server I get this error in the 3rd party library? How can I fix this?

Comment: I was migrating to Vite and fixed every obstacle but I just don't know what to do with one. Mine says `S is not a function` and nothing happens in the dev server at all. It should be a compilation problem and Webpack doesn't have it. I am aborting the migration

Comment: @MetehanAltuntekin have you checked your code/dependencies for circular references? (e.g. using https://github.com/pahen/madge).

Comment: I aborted the migration but couldn't stand just giving up. The other day I looked a little more into it with fresh mind and found it was related to importing `dayjs`. Accepted answer to this issue helped: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76754734/error-in-production-build-with-vite-react-error-in-uncaught-typeerror-is-n