# Error in production build with Vite & React: Error in Uncaught TypeError: _ is not a function

Tags: reactjs, typescript, axios, vite, production

I am using Vite, React, React Router and TypeScript for my website.
I have a problem when running the production build, in dev mode everything works fine.

When using the production build my browser shows a white background and I get the following error in my browser console:

[image]

The upper link brings me to the following (minified?) source code in line 70:

[image]

So maybe it has something to do with React Router?

But I am unsure what exactly causes this error.
Therefore, I will try to provide as much relevant information as I can below.

My results when running `npm run build`:

[image]

package.json:

```json
{
    "name": "frontend",
    "private": true,
    "version": "0.0.0",
    "type": "module",
    "scripts": {
        "start": "vite",
        "build": "tsc && vite build",
        "lint": "eslint src --ext ts,tsx --report-unused-disable-directives --max-warnings 0",
        "preview": "vite preview",
        "test": "jest"
    },
    "dependencies": {
        "@faker-js/faker": "^8.0.2",
        "@vitejs/plugin-react": "^4.0.3",
        "axios": "^1.4.0",
        "chart.js": "^4.3.0",
        "daisyui": "^3.1.7",
        "dayjs": "^1.11.9",
        "i18next": "^23.2.7",
        "i18next-browser-languagedetector": "^7.1.0",
        "lucide-react": "^0.258.0",
        "react": "^18.2.0",
        "react-chartjs-2": "^5.2.0",
        "react-dom": "^18.2.0",
        "react-i18next": "^13.0.1",
        "react-router-dom": "^6.14.2",
        "vite": "^4.4.6"
    },
    "devDependencies": {
        "@tailwindcss/typography": "^0.5.9",
        "@types/axios": "^0.14.0",
        "@types/node": "^20.1.1",
        "@types/react": "^18.0.28",
        "@types/react-dom": "^18.0.11",
        "@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin": "^5.57.1",
        "@typescript-eslint/parser": "^5.57.1",
        "autoprefixer": "^10.4.14",
        "eslint": "^8.2.0",
        "eslint-config-airbnb": "^19.0.4",
        "eslint-config-prettier": "^8.8.0",
        "eslint-plugin-import": "^2.25.3",
        "eslint-plugin-jsx-a11y": "^6.5.1",
        "eslint-plugin-prettier": "^4.2.1",
        "eslint-plugin-react": "^7.28.0",
        "eslint-plugin-react-hooks": "^4.3.0",
        "eslint-plugin-react-refresh": "^0.3.4",
        "jest": "^29.5.0",
        "postcss": "^8.4.23",
        "prettier": "^2.8.8",
        "prettier-plugin-tailwindcss": "^0.2.8",
        "tailwindcss": "^3.3.2",
        "typescript": "^5.0.2"
    }
}
```

vite.config.ts:

```
import { defineConfig } from "vite";
import react from "@vitejs/plugin-react";

// https://vitejs.dev/config/
export default defineConfig({
    plugins: [react()],
});
```

tsconfig.json:

```json
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "target": "ESNext",
        "lib": ["DOM", "DOM.Iterable", "ESNext"],
        "module": "ESNext",
        "skipLibCheck": true,

        /* Bundler mode */
        "moduleResolution": "bundler",
        "allowImportingTsExtensions": true,
        "resolveJsonModule": true,
        "isolatedModules": true,
        "noEmit": true,
        "jsx": "react-jsx",

        /* Linting */
        "strict": true,
        "noUnusedLocals": true,
        "noUnusedParameters": true,
        "noFallthroughCasesInSwitch": true
    },
    "include": ["src"],
    "references": [{ "path": "./tsconfig.node.json" }]
}
```

tsconfig.node.json:

```json
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "composite": true,
        "skipLibCheck": true,
        "module": "ESNext",
        "moduleResolution": "bundler",
        "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true
    },
    "include": ["vite.config.ts"]
}
```

When using `npm start` everything works as expected, but if I use `npm run build` and then `npm run preview` I get the error mentioned above and my browser shows a white background.

### What I already tried

I already tried to disable code splitting in Vite by using the following vite.config.ts:

```js
import { defineConfig } from "vite";
import react from "@vitejs/plugin-react";

// https://vitejs.dev/config/
export default defineConfig({
    plugins: [react()],
    build: {
        rollupOptions: {
            output: {
                manualChunks: {},
            },
        },
    },
});
```

This did not have any effect however.

I tried replacing out all my fragments in React:

```
<>
    ...
</>
```

with:

```
<Fragment>
    ...
<Fragment/>
```

But this also did not have any effect.

Comment: Line 70 in that minified code screenshot appears to be related to axios, returning some axios headers. Can you [edit] to replace all the screen captures of errors and code with ***actual*** formatted and readable text and code snippets? If there is an accompanying error stacktrace please also include that.

Comment: @DrewReese Your reply made me take a close look at the minified code and I found the problem :) I posted an answer explaining how to fix it.
Thank you so much for pointing me in the right direction :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I found the problem.

@DrewReese pointed me in the right direction and I actually took a good look at the minified code.

I realized that the code above was about date formatting and that I use a library called [Day.js](https://day.js.org/en/).

I fixed the problem by changing my imports from:

```
import * as dayjs from "dayjs";
import * as customParseFormat from "dayjs/plugin/customParseFormat";
```

to:

```
import dayjs from "dayjs";
import customParseFormat from "dayjs/plugin/customParseFormat";
```

Side note:

Day.js actually [seems to recommend](https://day.js.org/docs/en/installation/typescript#have-trouble-importing-dayjs) the first way of importing their library for my setup which breaks in the production build.

Comment: This was the same issue for me and your solution helped me, thanks!

Comment: Had this same problem in a Vue.js build without typescript, and your solution worked. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The issue is typescript version issue , if you are using the vite + react + typescript then you need to convert the app to create-react-app with typescript template `npx create-react-app app-name  --template typescript` then you need to convert the vite configuration to react app configuration like env setting.

```
vite - import.meta.env.VITE_ENV_NAME

cra - process.env.REACT_APP_ENV_NAME
```

then build the app and run the build locally.